# [ROS2] What is the "rqt --force-discover" option meaning?

Tags: ros, ros2, rqt-graph, ros-crystal, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, experts.
My environment is Ubuntu 18, ROS2 Crystal.

I installed the rqt-graph plugin to debugging.
But, I can't find out the plugin on rqt-gui.
In normal case, It should to be on "Plugins->introspection->Node Graph".

After `$ rqt ---force-discover`, it is working now.
Further, other plugins come out on "Plugins" tap.

**What is the "rqt --force-discover" option meaning?**

The description, written on the rqt usage guide, said below.

"--force-discover      force a rediscover of plugins"

Do you explain "rediscover" progress meaning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338282/%5Bros2%5D-what-is-the-%22rqt---force-discover%22-option-meaning?/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2019-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-11-21**:
Please remember to only ask the question once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The list of available plugins is cached for one day (https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/blob/bccb8a2066116f105a9765146576bdedaf174263/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py#L61) to speed up repeated invocation of `rqt`. If plugins are added within that period they don't show up automatically since the cached information is used.

Passing `--force-discover` will invalidate the existing cache and ensures that the list of available is queried again (which takes a little bit of time, depending on the size of the ROS installation up to a few seconds).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1